# Update Url without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I just want to update url in my reactjs app without refreshing page or re-rendering my component. How can I achieve this thing?

I'm trying to do this as follows:

```
this.props.location.query.t = searchQuery;
    hashHistory.replace(this.props.location);
```

But it doesn't work in my case.

Here is example for more elaboration:

**Current URL:** `http://localhost:3000/categories/Nts`

**Required URL:** `http://localhost:3000/Search?subcategory=NtsApp`

P.s. I have this string `Search?subcategory=NtsApp` in `searchQuery` variale

Comment: Have you tried using the [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History) object? Specifically [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox pardon me, but from where I can import `pushstate` function? I was importing it from `redux-router`. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What environment does this app run in? If it's a browser then the history object doesn't need to be imported, as it's a globally accessible object.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just used `histroy.pushstate`. Url is updated now but it also re-routed

Comment: It shouldn't be... `"Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState()"`. Unless something in redux is listening to `onpopstate`event.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use react-router for it. Let's say you want to update url on button click, with _onButtonClick method. It should look like this:

```
_onButtonClick () {
    const { pathname } = this.props.location; // I asume you are on page Search

    // query should be an object, so in your case it will be
    const query = { subcategory: 'NtsApp' };  

    this.context.router.replace({
        pathname: pathname,
        query: query
    })
}
```

You only have to specify your component contextTypes:

```
YourComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Above will only work on top-level components (managed by react-router). To make it work on child components, you have to pass location in context:

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            location: this.props.location
        };
    }

}
ChildComponent.childContextTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

And use it instead of this.props.location. I think that will do the job :)
For more information, I recommend you to familiarize with [react-router API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md)